# How can I call POST method on "offer" endpoint with sdp details?

Tags: java, android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I am new to WebRTC and I have lots of confusion regarding this. I don't know what I am asking here is possible or not?

I want to do live streaming of video from android to web. I did basic setup and reached to  step where we can able to create offer.

Transfer of offer and answer as SDP can happen over RTCDataChannel.

How can I send live video streaming data to backend using WebRTC ?

What I did till now is here.

```
 public class MediaTestNew extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory;
    MediaConstraints audioConstraints;
    MediaConstraints videoConstraints;
    MediaConstraints sdpConstraints;
    VideoSource videoSource;
    VideoTrack localVideoTrack;
    AudioSource audioSource;
    AudioTrack localAudioTrack;
    SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper;

    SurfaceViewRenderer localVideoView;
    SurfaceViewRenderer remoteVideoView;

    Button hangup;
    PeerConnection localPeer,remotePeer;
    List<IceServer> iceServers;
    EglBase rootEglBase;

    private static final String TAG = "MediaTestNew";

    boolean gotUserMedia;
    List<PeerConnection.IceServer> peerIceServers = new ArrayList<>();

    final int ALL_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, ALL_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        } else {
            // all permissions already granted
            start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == ALL_PERMISSIONS_CODE
                && grantResults.length == 2
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // all permissions granted
            start();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        // keep screen on
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        initViews();
        initVideos();
        getIceServers();
        initPeerConnectionFactory();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        hangup = findViewById(R.id.end_call);
        localVideoView = findViewById(R.id.local_gl_surface_view);
        remoteVideoView = findViewById(R.id.remote_gl_surface_view);
        hangup.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initVideos() {
        rootEglBase = EglBase.create();
        localVideoView.init(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
        remoteVideoView.init(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
        localVideoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        remoteVideoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    }

    private void initPeerConnectionFactory(){
        //Initialize PeerConnectionFactory globals.
        PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions =
                PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(this)
                        .createInitializationOptions();
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);

        //Create a new PeerConnectionFactory instance - using Hardware encoder and decoder.
        PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
        DefaultVideoEncoderFactory defaultVideoEncoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
                rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(),  /* enableIntelVp8Encoder */true,  /* enableH264HighProfile */true);
        DefaultVideoDecoderFactory defaultVideoDecoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
        peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
                .setOptions(options)
                .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
                .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
                .createPeerConnectionFactory();

        //Now create a VideoCapturer instance.
        VideoCapturer videoCapturerAndroid;
        videoCapturerAndroid = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(false));

        //Create MediaConstraints - Will be useful for specifying video and audio constraints.
        audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

        //Create a VideoSource instance
        if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
            surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThread", rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
            videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid.isScreencast());
            videoCapturerAndroid.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, this, videoSource.getCapturerObserver());
        }
        localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("100", videoSource);

        //create an AudioSource instance
        audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);
        localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("101", audioSource);

        if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
            videoCapturerAndroid.startCapture(1024, 720, 30);
        }

        localVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // And finally, with our VideoRenderer ready, we
        // can add our renderer to the VideoTrack.
        localVideoTrack.addSink(localVideoView);

        localVideoView.setMirror(true);
        remoteVideoView.setMirror(true);

        gotUserMedia = true;

        createPeerConnection();
        doCall();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    private VideoCapturer createCameraCapturer(CameraEnumerator enumerator) {
        final String[] deviceNames = enumerator.getDeviceNames();

        // First, try to find front facing camera
        Logging.d(TAG, "Looking for front facing cameras.");
        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            if (enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
                Logging.d(TAG, "Creating front facing camera capturer.");
                VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);

                if (videoCapturer != null) {
                    return videoCapturer;
                }
            }
        }

        // Front facing camera not found, try something else
        Logging.d(TAG, "Looking for other cameras.");
        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            if (!enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
                Logging.d(TAG, "Creating other camera capturer.");
                VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);

                if (videoCapturer != null) {
                    return videoCapturer;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void getIceServers() {
        PeerConnection.IceServer peerIceServer = PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer();
        peerIceServers.add(peerIceServer);
    }

    /**
     * Creating the local peerconnection instance
     */
    private void createPeerConnection() {
        PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(peerIceServers);
        // TCP candidates are only useful when connecting to a server that supports
        // ICE-TCP.
        rtcConfig.tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.DISABLED;
        rtcConfig.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXBUNDLE;
        rtcConfig.rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.REQUIRE;
        rtcConfig.continualGatheringPolicy = PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY;
        // Use ECDSA encryption.
        rtcConfig.keyType = PeerConnection.KeyType.ECDSA;

        //creating localPeer
        localPeer = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, new CustomPeerConnectionObserver("localPeerCreation") {
            @Override
            public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
                super.onIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
                onIceCandidateReceived(iceCandidate);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
                showToast("Received Remote stream");
                super.onAddStream(mediaStream);
                //gotRemoteStream(mediaStream);
            }
        });



        addStreamToLocalPeer();
    }

    /**
     * Adding the stream to the localpeer
     */
    private void addStreamToLocalPeer() {
        //creating local mediastream
        MediaStream stream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream("102");
        stream.addTrack(localAudioTrack);
        stream.addTrack(localVideoTrack);
        localPeer.addStream(stream);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the app is the initiator - We generate the offer and send it over through socket
     * to remote peer
     */
    private void doCall() {
        sdpConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        sdpConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "false"));
        sdpConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "false"));
        sdpConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("Testing", "local"));

        //creating Offer
        localPeer.createOffer(new CustomSdpObserver("localCreateOffer") {
            @Override
            public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                super.onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription);
                localPeer.setLocalDescription(new CustomSdpObserver("localSetLocalDesc"), sessionDescription);
                Log.d("onCreateSuccess", "SignallingClient emit ");
            }
        }, sdpConstraints);
    }

    /**
     * Received local ice candidate. Send it to remote peer through signalling for negotiation
     */
    public void onIceCandidateReceived(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
        //we have received ice candidate. We can set it to the other peer.
            remotePeer.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
    }

    public void showToast(final String msg) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(MediaTestNew.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //SignallingClient.getInstance().close();
        super.onDestroy();

        if (surfaceTextureHelper != null) {
            surfaceTextureHelper.dispose();
            surfaceTextureHelper = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> For Android there is less tutorial available or I am not good at my googling skill.
>
> Here, http://myhexaville.com/?s=webrtc all WebRTC detail available and all demo code. It's really good to understand all basics.